# AWS : Running Rekognition on DeepLens device

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-rekognition, aws-deeplens

I am creating a DeepLens project to recognise people, when one of select group of people are scanned by the camera.

The project uses a lambda, which processes the images and triggers the 'rekognition' aws api.

On AWS lambda console ( which has 1.8.9 boto version ), I get following issue when I try to call an AWS python API:

Note : *img_str* is a byte array

```
img_str = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)[1].tostring()
image = { 'Bytes': img_str }
response = rekognition.search_faces_by_image(CollectionId = 'TestingCollection', Image = { "Bytes" : image } )
```

**First error** : sendall() argument 1 must be string or buffer, not dict

**Reason in my understanding** : { "Bytes" : image } is a Json and NOT a string

**My Solution** : Make the json a string ( not sure whether I can concatenate img_str ( a byte array )

```
image = '{ "Bytes" :' + img_str + '}'
response = rekognition.search_faces_by_image(CollectionId = 'TestingCollection', Image = { "Bytes" : image } )
```

**Now error** : Error in face detection lambda: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 52: ordinal not in range(128)

**Question**
How do I concatenate a byte array (img_str) with strings without losing the array ?

Can i convert *image* variable to string WITHOUT *getting the can't decode byte 0xff* exception ? or

Can we do something else to overcome this issue ?

Thanks in advance guys !!

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar and this piece of code worked for me:

```
    # img is an image object (numpy array)
    success, img = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)
    image= img.tobytes()
    response=client.search_faces_by_image(CollectionId='TestingCollection',
                                        Image={'Bytes':image})
```